# /wp-admin/ doesn't work but /admin/ does

Tags: wp-admin, login

When I try to login via domain.com/wp-admin/ it will not allow me to do so. However, when I log in via domain.com/admin/ it will allow me to login with no problems.

Does anyone have any ideas as to why this is? And possibly how to fix this?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In general you can change where items link with [WP Constants](https://codex.wordpress.org/Determining_Plugin_and_Content_Directories#Constants). But according to [`get_admin_url()`](https://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/tags/4.5.3/src/wp-includes/link-template.php#L3106) it's possible the URL was filtered with `admin_url` in which case you might be able to add a filter with a high priority and override what is being sent. The default is;

```
$url = get_site_url($blog_id, 'wp-admin/', $scheme);

if ( $path && is_string( $path ) )
    $url .= ltrim( $path, '/' );

return apply_filters( 'admin_url', $url, $path, $blog_id );
```

As stated before, you should check your installed plugins (mainly security plugins) or `.htaccess` for wild redirects. Try disabling all plugins to narrow down that aspect pretty quick. Be sure to check the `/wp-content/mu-plugins/` folder for auto-loaded plugins.

If you can, search your theme and plugins for any reference to `admin` as well as search your database for `admin` to see where it might be set.

Answer (score 0):

It could be a plugin installed on the site for security purposes, to restrict bots from accessing to the wp-admin.

Or it could be settings in your .htaccess file. You can reverse the changes either way.

Comment: Not very helpful to me, as it doesn't provide a way around it. But thanks!